# JAXB getting Attribute value from child

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I cannot seems to get attribute information from Child in xml. I tried several different approaches and non of them worked. (getting attribute information from parent works fine)

- I'm working with JAXB library
- XML is nested -+ 300K lines

Here is short version on my XML

```
<HarnessContainer xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="xxx" Signature="15D823AAFC2CC91A61E1755C76E621"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Harness HarnessName="" HarnessDate="13.08.2019">
        <!--...-->
    </Harness>
</HarnessContainer>
```

Here is my parent class

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "HarnessContainer")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class HarnessContainer implements Serializable {


    private Harness harness;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "Signature")
    private String Signature;

    public HarnessContainer() {
    }

    public HarnessContainer(Harness harness, String signature) {
        this.harness = harness;
        Signature = signature;
    }
    //setters and getters
}
```

Here is my child class

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Harness")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Harness implements Serializable {


    @XmlAttribute(name = "HarnessDate")
    private String harnessDate;

    public Harness() {
    }

    public Harness(String harnessDate) {
        this.harnessDate = harnessDate;
    }
    //setters and getters
}
```

This is the invoking class

```
   public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException, IOException {

        File xmlFile = new File("C:\\Users\\Mini\\Desktop\\Desktop\\file.xml");
        JAXBContext jaxbContext;
        try {
            jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(HarnessContainer.class);
            Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();

            HarnessContainer harnessContainer = (HarnessContainer) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(xmlFile);

            System.out.println(harnessContainer.getHarness().getHarnessDate());

        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I chose to use @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD) because I'm planning to have many fields and this accessory type seems to best for that. I also tried different annotation's non of them worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem isn't that the `Harness` XML attribute is not being mapped, your problem is that the entire `Harness` object is not being mapped.

That's because the default element name is not the name in the XML. To fix, specify the name:

```
@XmlElement(name = "Harness")
private Harness harness;
```

The `harness` field will now not be null, and the `harnessDate` will not be null.